# Convert int with annotation to long

Tags: c#, sql, .net, excel, long-integer

I have a program that reads list of Excel files, the files are with different order of the columns, I have a code that identifies the telephone number field and read it from each Excel sheet.
The thing that the telephone number is returned always in the following syntax "9.7150135791e+011", I can't perform `SELECT FORMAT(part_no, ""######"") As part_no FROM [" & strSheet & "]  "` in the SQL statement, because I can't guess the index or name of the column.

I want something in the C# side to solve this, I mean some convert method to convert what I receive to what it really was before.
Any ideas?

Comment: That's not an `int`.  Well, technically, I guess it is, but Excel is probably storing it in some other way, like floating-point.

Comment: Yeah you're gonna need a bigger boat, like int64

Comment: Just keep it as a string and strip off the `.` and `e+011`.  Doesn't seem practical to make a telephone number an integer anyways.

Comment: @FelixCastor True, just read it as a `string` and `split` the `.` and `e`

Comment: Actually the number is formatted in the excel as a valid phone number(971501357909) but when I read it with the OleDbConnection it changes to be 9.7150135791e+011, so as you can see ignoring +011 will not return it to the original state

Answer (score 0):

Parse it as a `double`, and then cast it to a `long`.

```
var number = decimal.Parse("9.7150135791e+011");
var result = (long)number;
```

Or, you can simply reformat the string:

```
var result = "9.7150135791e+011".Split("e")[0]; // ...etc.
```

Or you can, y'now, format the original Excel column as a string so that you don't have to go through all this rigamarole.

Comment: That doesn't work. Double.Parse does, but I'm not sure that the result is a valid phone number.

Comment: Would it be better suited to have excel format the data without the `e` notation?  Give an integer instead of a real number?  Should be able to format an excel column to do so easily.

Comment: This is supposed to be a phone number?  Why are we trying to manipulate it as a number?

Comment: @RobertHarvey My thoughts exactly.  It should not be in that format to begin with.  Should be adjusted in excel so it can be directly used.

Comment: Actually the number is formated in the excel as a valid phone number(971501357909) but when I read it with the OleDbConnection it changes to be 9.7150135791e+011, so as you can see ignoring +011 will not return it to the orignial state!